# What is the ByteBuddy recipe for building an upper-bounded wildcard?

Tags: byte-buddy

I know some of this, but not all of it.  Most notably, I am aware of `TypeDescription.Generic.Builder` but I have a very specific question about it.

Suppose I want to build `Supplier<? extends Frob<X>>`.

Suppose further that all I *know* I have is a `TypeDefinition` for the parameter, but I don't know what it represents (in the example above it would represent `Frob<X>`).  That is, I don't know whether the `TypeDefinition` I have is a class, a parameterized type, a generic array type, a type variable, a wildcard, or anything else; I just know it's a `TypeDefinition`.

Obviously if I wanted to make `Supplier<Frob<X>>`, I could just do:

```
TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(Supplier.class),
                                                  myTypeDefinition)
  .build();
```

…assuming I haven't made any typos in the snippet above.

How can I make an upper-bounded wildcard `TypeDefinition` out of an existing `TypeDefinition` suitable for supplying as the "parameterized" part of a parameterized type build?  Is there an obvious recipe I'm overlooking, or is this a gap in the builder's DSL?

(I'm aware of the `asWildcardUpperBound()` method on `TypeDescription.Generic.Builder`, but that presumes I have a builder to work with, and in order to "bootstrap" such a builder I would need to give it a `TypeDescription` at the very least.  But I don't have a `TypeDescription`; I have a `TypeDefinition` which might be parameterized, and I don't want to use `asErasure()`.)

(I'm sort of looking for a way to do `TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(myTypeDefinition).asWildcardUpperBound().build()`, but I can't obviously do that.)

There does seem to be [`TypeDescription.Generic.OfWildcardType.Latent::boundedAbove`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.11.2/net/bytebuddy/description/type/TypeDescription.Generic.OfWildcardType.Latent.html#boundedAbove-net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription.Generic-net.bytebuddy.description.annotation.AnnotationSource-) but I can't tell if that's supposed to be an "internal use only" class/method or not.

Comment: From the top of my head, in Byte Buddy, there is `TypeDescriptionGenericBuilderTest` where any generic Java `Type` can be resolved to a `TypeDescription`. Wildcards can never be a top-level type which is why they are treated differently. I might need to move this test utility to the actual builder and to accept a `TypeDefinition`, that way it would become possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an API was indeed missing. I added an API in today's release (1.11.5) to translate an existing generic type description to a builder what allows transformations to arrays or wildcards. The API is `TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.of` which accepts a loaded or unloaded generic type description.